# Firebase-Installations: Error when communicating with the Firebase Installations server API. error: 403

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform

I'm implementing the standard tutorial for Firebase in my android app. I have two apps in firebase console under same project one is user which is working fine and other is driver which is stuck on Firebase Initialisation Error.

I have downloaded and changed the google-service.json file again from firebase console.
Also i matched the api key with the json file and values.xml (../debug/values.xml) But error remains the same every time. Can anyone help me please.

Comment: Have you invalidated cache and restarted, and did a clean build ?

Comment: Instead of describing what you did, show us the code that produces that error.

Comment: Please consider to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the stackoverflow `Help Center / asking`. You should at least include in your question what you have tried so far and where you got stuck. If your problem is with code you've written, you should include some.